# Is there a way to encrypt an existing ext4 filesystem with already data on it?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption

I have a big drive with **already data on it**, that I would like to encrypt (ext4).

Is there a way to encrypt that disk without having to move the data to another drive first?

---

Or maybe, this would be the better solution, once that question is solved:

[How do I create an auto-growing encrypted folder on linux?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34129/how-do-i-create-an-auto-growing-encrypted-folder-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Truecrypt, it allows you to encrypt a drive in place, although this takes longer than moving the data and rewrite it encrypted.

[This](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_encrypt_a_hard_drive_using_truecrypt.html) explains quite well how to do it. (edit: that is for Windows though, not entirely sure if it looks the same for every OS)

edit: nvm, Linux TrueCrypt supports fixed size only

Comment: that example is written for windows, and it assumes, your drive is empty

Comment: I read: "My external drive was full of data, so I choose Encrypt partition in place." and assume that his drive was not empty. I do not know which OS you use, please specify your question :) Truecrypt exists for many different operating systems.

Comment: @user1451340 If he is using a EXT4 file system, it is a safe enough bet he is using linux....

Comment: oh, right. my mind totally ignored that, sorry! Still, truecrypt works on many operating systems :)

Comment: Truecrypt should happily do this on Linux. +1

Comment: but how with data on it?

Comment: @RoryAlsop TrueCrypt works under Linux but it's a lot more limited. AFAIK it only supports fixed-size containers. Do you know otherwise?

Comment: I think you are right Gilles, fixed size only.

Comment: If you add `ecryptfs-setup-private` to your answer, I could accept it